# How to find out where line breaks(hyphen) are set in itext7

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

How to find out where line breaks are set?

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));

Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A4);

Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph()
            .setHyphenation(new HyphenationConfig("en", "EN", 2, 2))
            .add(new Text(bigString));

doc.add(paragraph);

doc.close();
```

*Here on the left, everything starts on the same level.:*

[image]

**I want to change margin-left after hyphen to each line margin-left was different:**

[image]

Can I find the line before the hyphen and the width to the hyphen?

I did it like this:

1) find out width of the page

```
MAX =  doc.getPdfDocument().getDefaultPageSize().getWidth() - (doc.getLeftMargin() + doc.getRightMargin());
```

2) I count width word

```
widthWordsAllLine +=  font.getWidth(words.get(i),22);
```

3) if (widthWordsAllLine +  font.getWidth(words.get(i),22)> MAX) i divide word .

4) Then i every words and divide word add to paragraph. and set paragraph.setMagrinLeft(10);

I did not describe everything because it would take a lot of time

**it works, but if I add a new feature, everything will not work(for example text align). Can it be implemented differently?**

Comment: _I did not describe everything because it would take a lot of time_ - It would be useful to know your end goal because solution may differ depending on the goal. What is the pattern of applying margins? I don't see any on the screenshot. The margins look random. Also, when you apply margins the problem might be that more text would fit (or less text), and thus it may affect all the content beyond some line. How do you solve this problem in your initial solution?

Comment: @AlexeySubach i need to change margins random(for example from 0 to 10).

Comment: @AlexeySubach i just  calculate how much should take the line.

Comment: But you want to preserve the line splitting that you got initially, right? So your margins should not affect the line splitting. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: It seems so, I just do not know English well :) i only teach him

Comment: it is pdf with my work https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ecaya4WcHYc4CF0j184tZfVQaN1Hqxv_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @AlexeySubach , i create Paragraph which fits in width. For example:
`String s =  "After the match Trump reiterated that titles take precedence over world ranking' . I divide this string in word(List<string>). And calculate every word+space:
for(String word :listWord)allWidth+=font.getWidth(word ,22); if word width+allWidth more then occupiedArea i divide word(which don't fit) Into syllables and calculate same`. For example, the string is  "After the match Trump reite-" and i do it: n doc.add(new Paragraph(After the match Trump reite-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of the question: The goal is to add random margins to each line of a paragraph so that when handwritten-like font is used it still looks like the text was written manually. Hyphenation should also be used and hence the original approach of trying to split the text into paragraphs.

The solution can be simpler, though. We can take the lines of a paragraph that are about to be drawn and shift them slightly just before drawing. All the features including hyphenation will be preserved.

It can be done with a custom renderer in a following way:

```
private static class CustomParagraphRenderer extends ParagraphRenderer {
    public CustomParagraphRenderer(Paragraph modelElement) {
        super(modelElement);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawChildren(DrawContext drawContext) {
        Random r = new Random();
        if (lines != null) {
            for (LineRenderer line : lines) {
                int leftMargin = r.nextInt(10);
                line.move(leftMargin, 0);
                line.draw(drawContext);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
        return new CustomParagraphRenderer((Paragraph) modelElement);
    }
}
```

Applying it to a paragraph is easy then:

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(longStr);
paragraph.setHyphenation(new HyphenationConfig("en", "US", 2, 2));
paragraph.setNextRenderer(new CustomParagraphRenderer(paragraph));
```

The result I got looks like this:

[image: output PDF]

Comment: THANKS! Do you know Russian?)

Comment: I do speak Russian, yes :)

Comment: Могу я спросить пару вопросов на русском?)

Comment: Например в вк, если ты не против)

Comment: @heavywar I think it would be fairer to ask the questions on StackOverflow since in that way someone with a similar question would be able to find the answer :)